# Universal iteration over all elements of: nested list, numpy array, pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I am trying to write a function that applies to each element of the argument provided, whether the argument is a nested python list, a numpy array or a pandas dataframe or series.

Example: (not working)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
b = np.array(a)
c = pd.DataFrame(a)

def printElement(x):
    print x

def iterateOverElements(arg):
    for element in arg:
        printElement(element)

iterateOverElements(a)
iterateOverElements(b)
iterateOverElements(c)
```

Desired output: printing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in new lines for each of the three calls. (Order is unimportant.)

True output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1 2 3 4 5]
[ 6  7  8  9 10]
0
1
2
3
4
```

As expected, the nested list iterates over its sub-lists, the numpy array over its rows and the pandas dataframe over its column labels.

**Is there a concise way to achieving my goal, or do I need to check the instance of the argument and construct different iteration codes for different types?** If I need to type-check, is there a way of importing e.g. pandas just to type-check and find out that it was a nested list after all?

Again, I do not care about the order in which I iterate over the elements, just that it is really the "basic" elements rather than some sub-collection.

Comment: Different types have indeed different ideas/designs how to iterate over their elements. Perhaps unfortunate, but that's how it currently is. You can thus either check the instance type, or, preferred, convert the value to the proper type before passing it into your function (something like `iterateOverElements(b.tolist())` or `iterateOverElements(c.values.tolist())`).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
def printElements(arg):
    x = arg.iterrows() if isinstance(arg, pd.DataFrame) else arg

    try:
        for element in x:
            printElements(element)
    except:
        print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn everything into a NumPy array and use the `flat` iterator:

```
def iterateOverElements(arg):
    for element in np.asarray(arg).flat:
        printElement(element)
```

Comment: This requires always having numpy imported even if iterateOverElements is called with a pure python nested list. This is something I would like ot avoid if possible. - But so far the most compact solution.